# link a twilio console user to a specific subaccount

Tags: url, navigation, console, twilio

The Twilio console has rich 10DLC UIs the spell out a lot of nice information for our customer support reps. And this information has been heavily in flux the last year, so it's not an attractive idea to reproduce it internally -- it will change quickly maybe. I'm hoping to make it easier for our support reps to navigate to these UIs.

Is it possible to link an internal support rep to a subaccount's console homepage (or any other subaccount pages), given the subaccount SID? The URL in my address bar is `https://console.twilio.com/` regardless of the subaccount I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

One mind-boggling solution seems to be:

1. have the user open this link in their browser (swap in `subaccount_sid` value) `https://www.twilio.com/console/account/api/v2/switch/<subaccount_sid>`
2. after possibly needing to login, that URL will show a blank result
3. navigate to console.twilio.com and you should be in that subaccount SID

Horrid solution but it's maybe still better than the multi-step process of doing it manually. How in the world isn't this easier?

Comment: What do you want to do with the URL? The CLI is very powerful and can be used to automate anything (in any subaccount).

Comment: @IObert The Twilio console has rich 10DLC UIs the spell out a lot of nice information for our customer support reps. And this information has been heavily in flux the last year, so it's not an attractive idea to reproduce it internally -- it will change quickly maybe. I'm hoping to make it easier for our support reps to navigate to these UIs.

Comment: Are you saying that this specific information is not provided by the API?

Comment: Have you known the API to provide carrier deadlines and updated pricing changes relating to 10DLC changes? Or maybe guidance around your brand/campaign registration that, if you reproduce internally, isn't promptly outdated when the API requirements change?

Comment: I see. Your are right, this is heavily in flux. Afaik there is not dedicated API for these information. Sorry